# Composing a smooth even function and square root

Tags: calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be smooth and satisfy $f(-x)=f(x)$ for all x. Define $g:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ by $g(x)=f(\sqrt{x})$. Is $g$ necessarily smooth at $0$?

I guess the answer is positive. $f$ being an even function implies that all its derivatives of odd order vanish at $0$, hence when substituting $\sqrt{x}$ in the Taylor series of $f$ around $0$, one obtains a power series in $x$. This is obviously not a proof, as most of the smooth functions are not analytic.

Showing that $f$ is differentiable is easy, and working a little harder one also shows that it is twice differentiable. It seems like it should work the same for derivatives of larger orders, and yet, I haven't found a satisfactory proof.

Comment: Well, it turns out that the answer is yes. My advisor showed me a nice nontrivial proof. If it is of interest to anyone, I can add a sketch of the proof.

Comment: $g$ is defined on $[0,\infty)$: all calculations you did regarding "smoothness at $0$ are just in suitable intervals of the formk $[0,\epsilon)$, with $\epsilon>0$, am I right?

Comment: Of course. When I say $g$ is smooth, I mean one can differentiate it from the right infinitely many times.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval: I would indeed be interested in seeing the argument. Do you still have it around? :)

Comment: @PhoemueX This is a challenge! I'll try and see if I can recover something. Will keep you posted.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval: Thank you very much for your effort, I hope I did not trouble you too much. In the meantime I found the following MO thread in which this question is also discussed: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77120/smoothness-of-f-sqrt-x . There is even a very nice solution using Fourier analysis :)  I am sorry for first bothering you, and then finding a solution elsewhere, but maybe the MO thread is also interesting for you :)